# Nested Controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: controller, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel4, and having issue setting up nested controllers. I have an "Admin" sub-directory in controllers directory, where admin controller reside.
My admin controllers extend an "AdminController" in my controller directory.
I have setup admin controllers like this

```
<?php
namespace Admin;

use AdminController;

class HomeController extends AdminController {

    public $layout = 'admin.layouts.master';

    public function index() {

        $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

and in my routes.php file

```
 /** Admin Routes **/
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.vigap.local'), function()
{
    //Dashboard
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index');

});
```

But when i navigate to http://admin.xyz.local, i get an error saying "Class 'Admin\View' not found".
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way your controller works, it's just that in the HomeController you use the `Admin` namespace, then in the index function you call the `View` class, but that class is not part of the `Admin` namespace and therefore you'll get an error saying that `Class Admin\View` could not be found.

Try doing one of the following two things:

`use View`

or

`$this->layout->content = \View::make('admin.dashboard');`

(note the backslash in front of `View`)

Answer (score 2):

`Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index');` means the `Admin` PHP `namespace`, not a subfolder of the `Controllers` directory.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers

From the Router's perspective, it doesn't matter where you put your controllers,
it only wants to know which class needs to be called when the route you're registering is requested.

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` should work, because the class loader will find your HomeController class, wherever it is.

Source: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9917

However, you probably already have a `HomeController` at the root of the controllers directory, so you'll have a classname clash. I recommend you rename your class to `AdminHomeController`

`Route::get('/', 'AdminHomeController@index');`

Also, don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` after adding new classes, so that the classmap is updated.

Comment: +1 for composer dump-autoload ... could you tell me what I need to read to understand this better, do I need to run this everytime I run a controller? So controllers as not registered the way they were in Laravel 3?

Comment: Only when adding new classes (new controllers). Composer maintains a list of php files an their classes for quick autoloading, so when you add new classes, you have to refresh composer's autoload file. I think Laravel will also try to find your controllers base on their names and the paths you've set in your laravel config.